# SD card corruption detection

Tags: linux, sd-card, corruption

Is there any way I can detect the SD card corruption at run time?

I have a situation where in firmware upgrade is affected because of SD card issue, however it will be known only after the upgrade fails. What I am looking for is the tests/any utilities which can be used to detect the SD card corruption on the go. Say, I run a check every day to see is if SD card fine or has corrupted? If corrupted, I can stall the upgrade and recommend SD card replacement or to take some other action.

It would be better if it is possible without a physical detaching of the SD card. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't rely on SD cards as storage for unique files. ALWAYS have a copy of whatever is on that card somewhere else. When it gets corrupted, it's already too late to take backups. You can make and test checksums for the files with the `sha256sum` tool.

Comment: Agreed. Can the Metadata of the files can be checked to verify whether SD card allows file updates or not?